# Fetch value from json request body and store in a variable in Azure API Management

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I want to fetch a value from json and store it in a variable in Azure API Management. 
JSON Example which is coming in request Body is

```
{
    "ItemCode": 1,
    "ItemName": "USA",
    "typeCode": "REG"
  }
```

I need to fetch value of ItemCode and typeCode and store it in a  variable.

I have check on Microsoft Docs and all it gives me to transform body by using  liquid template which I suppose is of no use in my requirement.

I have stored a JSON in a variable like

```
set-variable name="varItemCode" value="@(context.Request.Body.As<String>(preserveContent:true))" />
```

Since this is stored a string I am not able to traverse the JSON Object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to do it

```
<kbd>set-variable name="varTypeCode" value="@{
                    JObject json = JObject.Parse(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("varBody"));
                    var typeCode = json.GetValue("typeCode");
                    return typeCode;
                 }" />
```

Answer (score 2):

this is working

```
 <set-variable name="validationResults" value="@(context.Request.Body.As<JObject>())" />
    
<set-variable name="operation" value="@((string)((JObject)context.Variables["validationResults"])["operation"])" />
```